# App_Browsers .browser definition files not working with HTTPS

Tags: .net, iis, ssl, user-agent, internet-explorer-11

I am using .NET Framework 4.0 application. At this stage it cannot be upgraded to 4.5

Previously, it failed to detect the IE11 version. So I added App_browsers folder with ie.browser file and it worked for me. But when I tested it over HTTPS it fails again. It seems it is not picking the app_browsers folder.

Does any one know the reason? Any help would be appreciated.